# Trying to populate a select box with sql data, and my query produces duplicate elements (PHP, SQL)

Tags: mysql

I am using PHP to fill a select box with data. I then have an if statement to check if the current option in the while loop is the one that should be selected.

I have set organized both while loops in my PHP the same way, but the `Name`, `ID` loop does not work, whilst the `Desc`, `ID` loop does work and sets the selected option as it is meant to.

Also, I know this code is vulnerable. I plan to secure it once I have gotten functionality working.

Comment: You're using `fetchObject()` twice, that's why.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I removed one of them and got undefined property error. Could you explain what I need to change and what it needs to change to?

Comment: Replace `$rowObj = $venueNameQueryResult->fetchObject();
            $currentVenueID = $rowObj->venueID;` with `$currentVenueID = ''`

Comment: @Nick thanks for your input, but that does not work. My goal is to have the current value to be already select if that wasn't clear. Any ideas?

Comment: @badAtPHP I see what you're saying. At present though `$currentVenueID = $rowObj->venueID;` is assigning an indeterminate value to `$currentVenueID`. I think you need some other way of assigning `$currentVenueID` other than the first row of the result of your query.

Comment: @Nick OK. But how come the same method works in the case of the loop above?

Comment: In the other loop you're getting `$currentCatID` from the output of `$sqlQuery` - perhaps this is where you should be getting `$currentVenueID` from too? i.e. after `$currentCatID = $rowObj->catID;` add `$currentVenueID = $rowObj->venueID;` so it happens before you assign a new value to `$rowObj`

Comment: @Nick This mostly works how I want it tow. Only problem is that the very first item that should be in the list now no longer appears. When I Replace $rowObj = $venueNameQueryResult->fetchObject(); $currentVenueID = $rowObj->venueID; with $currentVenueID = '' like you said before. It does appear, if this is any indication. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @badAtPHP if you now have the assignment to `$currentVenueID` earlier then you can simply delete the two lines: `$rowObj = $venueNameQueryResult->fetchObject(); $currentVenueID = $rowObj->venueID;`

Comment: @Nick Thanks, you are a life saver :)

Comment: I see @Nick helped solve this. Maybe he'd like to put an answer together? Sorry, I wasn't around earlier, had to do something.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I've posted an answer.

Comment: I noticed @Nick ;-) Cheers

Comment: Where's all that code? Why did you remove it from the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems. Firstly, you are getting your `$currentVenueID` from the wrong place, it should be set as a result from the first query (`$sqlQuery`). Secondly, your `$rowObj = $venueNameQueryResult->fetchObject();` is effectively removing the first venue from your venue list. To solve this, move

```
$currentVenueID = $rowObj->venueID;
```

to before `$rowObj` is reassigned after the first query, e.g. put it immediately after

```
$currentCatID = $rowObj->catID;
```

Then you can safely remove

```
$rowObj = $venueNameQueryResult->fetchObject();
```

and the code should work fine.